# Jquery Loop through list and replace

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a way to loop through a list with Jquery, and if a certain class has text of "Not Complete", replace the words "Not Complete" with a animated gif.

Here's the list:

```
<ul>
<li class="name">Name</li>
<li class="job">This</li>
<li class="status">Not Complete</li>
</ul>
```

The list is populated via a php script.

I tired this from another example here, but couldn't get it to work:

```
function change(){
if($('.status').text=='Not Complete')
{$('.status').replaceWith('<img src='loading.gif' />');}
else{}
}

$(function() {
  $(".status").each(change);
});
```

Any idea's of how I could get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.status` elements just have short text snippets (not long paragraphs of text), it should be safe to use the [`contains-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
$('li.status:contains(Not Complete)').html("<img src='loading.gif' />");
```

---

Notice that I alternated the quotation marks in the HTML. You used only single quotes, which was terminating the string prematurely.

I also added the [`element-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) since `:contains()` is not a standard selector. This will speed things up because now it will only have to look at `<li>` elements.

---

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PahVB/1/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the `text()` function:

```
$('.status').text() == ...
```

Your code checks whether the function itself is equal to `'Not Complete'`.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is populated by PHP, why not just make PHP put it in there in the first place?

But if you're sticking with the jQuery, it should be text()==, not just text==.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - you need to rewrite this a little as you are currently running a loop, but then within the loop querying the collection again with if($('.status')

Try this:

```
 $(function() {
      $(".status").each(function(){
           if($(this).text() == 'Not Complete'){
              $(this).replaceWith('<img src='loading.gif' />');
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(".status").each(function()
{
    if($(this).text() == "Not Complete")
    {
        $(this).html("<img src='loading.gif' />");
    }
});

</script>
```

Maybe give this a try

Answer (score 0):

The each function typically passes a parameter for index and object of the array you are iterating over. In your function you reselect the array each time. Try something like:

```
$(".status").each(function(index, value) {  
    if ($(this).text()=="Not Complete")  
    {  
        $(this).replaceWith($("<img />").attr("src","loading.gif"));  
    }  
}
```

This is based on the jQuery documentation for the each function http://api.jquery.com/each/